# Did radare2 remove support of MSIL from some version?

Tags: radare2

When I read the radare2 book here: https://radare.gitbooks.io/radare2book/content/

It said it support MSIL: " _d 16 32 64 msil PD .NET Microsoft Intermediate Language " However, when I git clone current version and compile it. It doesn't show this option. Did it remove the support of .NET from some version?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it seems to be the case, they just didn't update the radar2 book, here is the update that removes mentioning MSIL as one of the platforms: [Github radare2 book merged pull request for the correction](https://github.com/radare/radare2book/pull/60/files)

Comment: oh thanks. I've did the pull-request for r2 but forgot to mention it here :)